# refresh div section after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery

I have a content data which contains all session information. I want to refresh that div section in which i display session information. For example i have a cart page in which several products are shown in cart session, when user click on delete button ajax send a request to server where i delete product from session and on success jquery refresh cart div to show updated session data. I dont want to generate html on server side and replace it with existed html on success of ajax call. If i able to refresh that div section it will automatically displayed updated session information. **I Just want to refresh div section which store session information after ajax call ?**

Answer (score 1):

To refresh the div data, simply after your success function clear the div and populate with the new data.

```
success:function(data){
  $('#divid').html();
  $('#divid').html(data);
}
```

**data will be your updated session data.**

Comment: I just want to refresh a specific div and i have no data to be replace with existing data. Any jquery function you know to perform refresh functionality ?

Comment: there is no function for refresh functionality in jquery as such. Jquery can only process your server side data . So write a custom function to fetch session data and call that same function on add/edit/del

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy you can do this by jQuery.

See the documentation of jQuery Ajax 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Thanks

Comment: I tried, but i dont find any method which i call on success to refresh div !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function after ajax call.

Syntax is :

```
$('#elementId').load('filename');
```

Refer the documentation for use.

Answer (score -1):

When call .load "file".. you can add specific div , for example:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```